# tatukgis, save & load layer properties

Tags: delphi, gis, tatukgis

If someone have some experiences with TatukGIS developer kernel product, can you explain how to programmatically save and load layer properties like in their free TatukGIS viewer product?

The environment i use were Delphi 7 and BDS 2006

thanks

Edit, this code don't work:

`var
  lyrPeta: TGIS_LayerSHP;
begin
  MapPath:= ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + '\maps\';
  lyrPeta:= TGIS_LayerSHP.Create;
  lyrPeta.Path:= MapPath + 'jabodetabek'+'_asjalan.shp';
  lyrPeta.Name:= 'jabodetabek'+'_asjalan.shp';
  lyrPeta.IgnoreShapeParams:= True;
  lyrPeta.UseConfig:= True;
  lyrPeta.ConfigName:= MapPath + 'jalan.ini';
  lyrPeta.ReadConfig;
  GIS_Viewer.Add(lyrPeta);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do this as below in VB6. I *think* our code was originally based on [this FAQ entry](http://www.tatukgis.com/faq/question.aspx?show=/faq/store/q10668.htm). It [makes](http://www.tatukgis.com/faq/question.aspx?show=/faq/store/q10400.htm) the Tatuk control save an INI file with the layer properties. I believe it automatically reloads the layer properties when the app starts again. If you only want one file, rather than one file per layer, you could [try](http://www.tatukgis.com/faq/question.aspx?show=/faq/store/q10371.htm) a TTKGP file.

```
With layer ' the layer is an XGIS_LayerVector '
  .StoreParamsInProject = False
  .ConfigName = "c:\test\mylayer.ini" ' a separate INI file for each layer '
  .WriteConfig
  .SaveAll
End With
```

EDIT: And loading again - I think this is **after** the layer has been added to the GIS control.

```
With layer ' the layer is an XGIS_LayerVector '
  .StoreParamsInProject = False
  .ConfigName = "c:\test\mylayer.ini" ' a separate INI file for each layer '
  .RereadConfig
End With
```

IMHO the Tatuk help and samples are hard to understand, although the product itself is pretty powerful. It's worth trying the [forum](https://shop.tatukgis.com/Forum/forumIn.aspx) for Tatuk questions as well, although you need a support agreement to access it :(

Comment: thanks, i never realize about ConfigName & WriteConfig (but i know about SaveAll), i will investigate this

Comment: can you give solution for reading the config by selecting the config file? i have it like in my question, but somehow it can't work

Comment: Have done, I've also added a link to an FAQ page on Tatuk - I *think* our code was originally based on this. http://www.tatukgis.com/faq/question.aspx?show=/faq/store/q10668.htm

Comment: thanks again for reply, i'm still evaluating tatukgis (use trial), and we will buy the retail when our project start

Comment: A contractor wrote our Tatuk code for us, and we're now maintaining it. We're fairly happy with the code and the product's powerful, we just struggle to work out how to do anything new. We use the help, samples and forum but still find it difficult. How are you getting on?

Comment: Hi @MarkJ :) I am working with Tatuk for 1.5 year now and generaly I am impressed by the framework \ component. I've made some nice extentions to it. Do you have any perticular new feature on your mind?